# How to remove unused images from EKS worker nodes?

Tags: docker, amazon-eks

I want to delete all the unused images stored on the EKS worker node.
We can delete images from kubelet but how to achieve it in EKS?

Comment: added corn job to delete unused docker resources in userdata section of ec2 instance as follows: `echo "0 0 * * * /usr/bin/docker system prune -af" >> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user'